# Openerp how to change bar chart single column multi colour into multiple column?

Tags: javascript, odoo, bar-chart, flotr

The below bar chart code:-

```
var data = [
    {data: [[0, 5],[1,2],[2,4],[3,1]], label:'t1'},
    {data: [[0,2],[1, 5],[2,2],[3,3]], label:'t2'},
    {data: [[0,3],[1, 7],[2,5],[3,2]], label:'t3'},
    {data: [[0,4],[1, 3],[2,1],[3,4]], label:'t4'}
];

$.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
    series: {
        lines: {
            fill: true,
        },
        bars: {
            show: true,
            align:'center',
            barWidth: 0.8,
        }   
    },
    xaxis: {
        ticks: [[0, "Jan"],[1, "Feb"],[2, "Mar"],[3, "Apr"]]
    },
    yaxis: {
        min: 0
    }
});
```

The above code return the output

Example [fiddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUbjw.png).
[image]

How to get the below bar chart shows individual color for t1, t2, t3, t4 to corresponding month?... Based on this output what are the changes need in the code?...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The below code working to shows bar char individual color

```
var data = [
    {data: [[0, 5],[1,2],[2,4],[3,1]], label:'t1'},
    {data: [[0.2,2],[1.2, 5],[2.2,2],[3.2,3]], label:'t2'},
    {data: [[0.4,3],[1.4, 7],[2.4,5],[3.4,2]], label:'t3'},
    {data: [[0.6,4],[1.6, 3],[2.6,1],[3.6,4]], label:'t4'}
];

$.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
    series: {
        lines: {
            fill: true,
        },
        bars: {
            show: true,
            align:'center',
            barWidth: 0.1,
        }   
    },
    xaxis: {
        ticks: [[0.3, "Jan"],[1.3, "Feb"],[2.3, "Mar"],[3.3, "Apr"]]
    },
    yaxis: {
        min: 0
    }
});
```

But default data value shows **data = [{data:[[0,5]], label:'t1'}, data:[[0,2]], label:'t1'}, data:[[0,3]], label:'t1'}];**

How to update the data value for x axis 0, 0, 0 into  0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 dynamically?...